# Executing Hierarchical Query showing all data

Tags: sql, oracle11g, hierarchy

I was trying [Hierarchical](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm#SQLRF52318) `select` Query in oracle  but Can't  get the desire out put from there and don't under stand am i writing the wrong query or there is wrong data in my table my desire out put is like

```
I_ID    NAME    MGR_ID  LEVEL   PATH
1       SMITH       0    0      /SMITH
2       ALLEN       1    1      /SMITH/ALLEN
3       WARD        1    1      /SMITH/WARD
5       MARTIN      1    1      /SMITH/MARTIN
4       JONES       2    2      /SMITH/ALLEN/JONES
7       CLARK       2    2      /SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK
6       BLAKE       3    2      /SMITH/WARD/BLAKE
8       SCOTT       7    3      /SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/SCOTT
9       KING        7    3      /SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/KING
10      TURNER      8    4      /SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/SCOTT/TURNER
12      JAMES       8    4      /SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/SCOTT/JAMES
11      ADAMS       10   5      /SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/SCOTT/TURNER/ADAMS
13      FORD        11   6      /SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/SCOTT/TURNER/ADAMS/FORD
14      MILLER      13   7      /SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/SCOTT/TURNER/ADAMS/FORD/MILLER
```

Please help me out for reference please [check](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00805/5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used query similar to yours, and grouped the result to select only one row with max level for each i_ids.

**Query**:

```
select *
from (
    select
        i_id, name, mgr_id, max(plevel) - 1 "level",
        max(path) keep (dense_rank last order by plevel) path
from (
        select i_id, name, mgr_id, level plevel, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, '/') path
        from emp
        connect by prior i_id = mgr_id
    )
group by i_id, name, mgr_id
)
order by "level", i_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/00805/33/0)**:

```
| I_ID |   NAME | MGR_ID | LEVEL |PATH                                              |
|------|--------|--------|-------|--------------------------------------------------|
|    1 |  SMITH |      0 |     0 |/SMITH                                            |
|    2 |  ALLEN |      1 |     1 |/SMITH/ALLEN                                      |
|    3 |   WARD |      1 |     1 |/SMITH/WARD                                       |
|    5 | MARTIN |      1 |     1 |/SMITH/MARTIN                                     |
|    4 |  JONES |      2 |     2 |/SMITH/ALLEN/JONES                                |
|    6 |  BLAKE |      3 |     2 |/SMITH/WARD/BLAKE                                 |
|    7 |  CLARK |      2 |     2 |/SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK                                |
|    8 |  SCOTT |      7 |     3 |/SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/SCOTT                          |
|    9 |   KING |      7 |     3 |/SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/KING                           |
|   10 | TURNER |      8 |     4 |/SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/SCOTT/TURNER                   |
|   12 |  JAMES |      8 |     4 |/SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/SCOTT/JAMES                    |
|   11 |  ADAMS |     10 |     5 |/SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/SCOTT/TURNER/ADAMS             |
|   13 |   FORD |     11 |     6 |/SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/SCOTT/TURNER/ADAMS/FORD        |
|   14 | MILLER |     13 |     7 |/SMITH/ALLEN/CLARK/SCOTT/TURNER/ADAMS/FORD/MILLER |
```